# How do I add attributes to a link made with the image method from the HTMLHelper in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, html-helper

I'm using CakePHP.

This line of code will generate a `<img>` tag:

```
$html->image('image.png', array('alt', 'Alternative text'));
```

And this will generate the same thing, but it will make the image clickable:

```
$html->image('image.png', array('alt' => 'Alternative text', 'url' => 'http://www.example.com'));
```

So far I understand, but what can I do if I want to add attributes to the `<a>` tag.

Doing this:

```
$html->image('image.png', array('alt' => 'Alternative text', 'url' => 'http://www.example.com/', 'class' => 'aClass'));
```

Will add the attribute to `<img>` instead of `<a>`. The output is something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Alternative text" class="aClass" />
</a>
```

But I want something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" class="aClasse">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Alternative text" />
</a>
```

I tried to do like a `$html->link()` using a `$html->image()` as the first parameter but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to use the HTML helper `link` method and tell it to not escape the title, something it does by default, by adding the `'escape' => false` parameter. Please read the manual, it's explained there: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1442/link